# Integrate Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, polyline, react-leaflet

I'm wondering how I might integrate the Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim (https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim) and react-leaflet (https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) Leafletjs plugins.

I have a React app that uses react-leaflet to display some Polylines in the DOM. Like this:

```
<Polyline weight={4} color={ intToRGB(hashCode(session['session_id'])) } positions={session.waypoints.map(waypoint => [ waypoint.lat, waypoint.lng ])} />
```

It'd be nice if I could animate them such that they "snakein" like the aforementioned plugin allows. But since my Polylines are implemented as React component I'm not seeing how I would give this functionality to them.

I really like using the react-leaflet syntax and it would be a bummer if I had to port my app to VanillaJS to achieve this feature

Any help is appreciated!

https://github.com/caseysiebel/map-express/blob/master/client/components/Map.js

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible if you make a custom component that calls the snakeIn method.  You should be able to create a copy of [react-leaflet's Polyline class](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/Polyline.js).  In the copy you would import `Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim` and modify the `createLeafletElement` function.  I think you may have to also override the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` methods that get inherited from the `MapLayer` class to use a different signature of adding and removing the polyline to/from the map.

Comment: Thanks @Evan, could you please show any running example?